# Mysql 5.7 installation, Repository not getting listed

Tags: linux, installation, mysql, yum

I am tring to get MYSQL5.7 installed on Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago).

Per instructions I firstly add the repository. This works fine but when I do yum repolist all it doesn't show mysql there. Everything looks right but its not working as expected, Why ?

```
[root@mcsmyspr-labc01 tmp]#  yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm: mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch
Marking mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql57-community-release.noarch 0:el7-11 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=========================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                               Arch                               Version                             Repository                                                            Size
=========================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql57-community-release                             noarch                             el7-11                              /mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch                              31 k

Transaction Summary
=========================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total size: 31 k
Installed size: 31 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch                                                                                                                                               1/1
  Verifying  : mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch                                                                                                                                               1/1

Installed:
  mysql57-community-release.noarch 0:el7-11

Complete!
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very much like the repo hasn't been enabled inside the config file.

Navigate to; `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo` Inside you should find the following lines - you will have a few sections so check each one you need/want to use;

```
[mysql57-community]
name=MySQL 5.7 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

Note the line `enabled=0` that needs to be changed to `enabled=1` You should then be able to list the repo.

In your origional question it appears you have installed the CentOS 7 file (as denoted by the `el7` part) You should be using the CentOS 6 file which can be downloaded from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el6-1.noarch.rpm). (Remembering to enable the correct sections/versions)